# Remove last N rows in data frame with the arbitrary number of rows

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I have a data frame and I want to remove last N rows from it.
If I want to remove 5 rows, I currently use the following command, which in my opinion is rather convoluted:

```
df<- df[-seq(nrow(df),nrow(df)-4),]
```

How would you accomplish task, is there a convenient function that I can use in R?

In unix, I would use:

```
tac file | sed '1,5d' | tac
```

Comment: In unix, I would use: `head -n -5 file`

Answer (score 105, accepted):

`head` with a negative index is convenient for this...

```
df <- data.frame( a = 1:10 )
head(df,-5)
#  a
#1 1
#2 2
#3 3
#4 4
#5 5
```

p.s. your `seq()` example may be written slightly less(?) awkwardly using the named arguments `by` and `length.out` (shortened to `len`) like this `-seq(nrow(df),by=-1,len=5)`.

Comment: There's an edge case! `head(df, -0) == head(df,0) != df`

Comment: @peer sorry, I don't think I understand your comment. Can you illustrate the edge case more fully?

Comment: I'm switching from `df[0:(nrow(df)-n),]` to `head`. In my case the user moves a slider to indicate `n` last rows are to be removed.
But there's a catch! When the user sets `n=0` we would expect no rows to be removed. But with `head(df, -n)` all rows are removed because negative zero is resolved to positive zero -> take the first 0 rows. So I want to warn others who set `n` dynamically and allow `n=0`: You'll need `if (n > 0) df=head(df, -n)`

Answer (score 27):

This one takes one more line, but is far more readable:

```
n<-dim(df)[1]
df<-df[1:(n-5),]
```

Of course, you can do it in one line by sticking the `dim` command directly into the re-assignment statement.
I assume this is part of a reproducible script, and you can retrace your steps... Otherwise, strongly recommend in such cases to save to a different variable (e.g., `df2`) and then remove the redundant copy only after you're sure you got what you wanted.

Comment: While the `head` solution is probably preferable, you could also use `nrow(df)` instead of `dim(df)[1]`.

Comment: intuitive one-liner based on your suggestion: ``d <- d[1:(nrow(d)-5),]``

Comment: This solution actually removes the rownames of the data frame for me, while the accepted answer (using `head()`) doesn't, so I would not recommend this option.

Comment: One-liner for the one-liner kids out there: df = df[1:(nrow(df)-1),]

Answer (score 23):

Adding a `dplyr` answer for completeness:

```
test_df <- data_frame(a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), 
                      b = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"))
slice(test_df, 1:(n()-5))

## A tibble: 5 x 2
#      a b    
#  <dbl> <chr>
#1     1 a    
#2     2 b    
#3     3 c    
#4     4 d    
#5     5 e
```

Answer (score 22):

Another `dplyr` answer which is even more readable:

```
df %>% filter(row_number() <= n()-5)
```