# How to remove first N rows in a data set in R?

Tags: r

I saw this [stack-overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21148498/remove-last-n-rows-in-data-frame-with-the-arbitrary-number-of-rows) already. But what I want is to remove first N rows in my data set. I can't think of a solution as I am new to R.

Comment: Replace the 2 with N in the link and you have your answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In this case, we need the opposite, so `tail` can be used.

```
N <- 5
tail(df, -N)
#    a
#6   6
#7   7
#8   8
#9   9
#10 10
```

---

It can be wrapped in a function and specify a condition to return the full dataset if the value of `N` is negative or 0

```
f1 <- function(dat, n) if(n <= 0) dat else tail(dat, -n)
f1(df, 0)
f1(df, 5)
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame( a = 1:10 )
```

Comment: doesn't work for N=0

Comment: I may still want to drop N=0 rows

Answer (score 8):

Based on the `df` used in the example above:

```
N <- 5

df[-(1:N), , drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: `df[-(1:N),]` works for me, but what does `, drop = FALSE` add to it?

Comment: ``drop = FALSE`` ensures that, if df is a single column data.frame, the returned value will still be a data frame (and not get dimensions dropped and become a vector).