# Deleting a subset of rows based on other variables

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I have followed this example [Remove last N rows in data frame with the arbitrary number of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21148498/remove-last-n-rows-in-data-frame-with-the-arbitrary-number-of-rows) but it just deletes only the last 50 rows of the data frame rather than the last 50 rows of every study site within the data frame. I have a really big data set that has multiple study sites and within each study site there's multiple depths and for each depth, a concentration of nutrients.

I want to just delete the last 50 rows of depth for each station.

E.g. 
station 1 has 250 depths
station 2 has 1000 depths
station 3 has 150 depth

but keep all the other data consistent.

This just seems to remove the last 50 from the dataframe rather than the last 50 from every station...

```
 df<- df[-seq(nrow(df),nrow(df)-50),]
```

What should I do to add more variables (study site) to filter by?

Comment: What structure does your data have? can you share `dput(df)`

Comment: Does all station have atleast 50 rows of depth? Does something like this work? `df %>% group_by(station) %>% filter(row_number() < (n() - 50))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A potential base R solution would be:

```
d <- data.frame(station = rep(paste("station", 1:3), c(250, 1000, 150)),
                depth = rnorm(250 + 1000 + 150, 100, 10))

d$grp_counter <- do.call("c", lapply(tapply(d$depth, d$station, length), seq_len))
d$grp_length <- rep(tapply(d$depth, d$station, length), tapply(d$depth, d$station, length))
d <- d[d$grp_counter <= (d$grp_length - 50),]
d

# OR w/o auxiliary vars: subset(d, select = -c(grp_counter, grp_length))
```

Answer (score 1):

we can use `slice` function from `dplyr` package

```
df2<-df %>% group_by(Col1) %>% slice(1:(n()-4))
```

At first it groups by category column and if arranged in proper order it can remove last n number of rows (in this case 4) from dataframe for each category.

Comment: I get an error that says Error: Indices must be either all positive or all negative, not a mix of both. Found 1 positive indices and 9 negative indices

Comment: can you share sample data by providing output of dput(head(df, 50)) ? if i use data from @r.user.05apr then i am getting it correctly.

Comment: yes I get a correct answer with r.user.05apr but I get the error with df2<-df %>% group_by(Col1) %>% slice(1:(n()-4))

Comment: you can use this code: d2<-d %>% group_by(station) %>% slice(1:(n()-100))

Comment: I still get the same error: Error: Indices must be either all positive or all negative, not a mix of both. Found 1 positive indices and 16 negative indices